# How to move a 80GB MySQL Database with least effort and least time offline?

Tags: mysql

Im a software developer with 4 years experience but brand new in my company, my first job is to move a 80GB mySQL database from a very very small and old database server to a brand new. 
The problem: It is the alltime working database for nearly everything in my company... I can't reduce the data to less gb because it is all needed data. 
So: How to do this and how to achieve this with the least time offline so around 500 people can work again fastly...

Information requested for Help:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as '# TABLES', CONCAT(ROUND(sum(data_length) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') as DATA, CONCAT(ROUND(sum(index_length) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') as INDEXES, CONCAT(sum(ROUND(( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2)), 'G') as TOTAL, engine as ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY engine;
```

Answer:

```
3 NULL NULL NULL NULL   
13 1.36G 1.70G 3.05G InnoDB   
13 0.00G 0.00G 0.00G MEMORY   
1159 44.04G 34.89G 78.90G MyISAM
```

Comment: Are you using mainly InnoDB?

Comment: I have no idea, I never worked with MySQL before, Im windows developer with MS SQL... so it's a very hard job for me :) Where to find this information in phpmyadmin? I will look it up.

Comment: Okay, found the information :) Its all MyISAM

Comment: Execute this and tell us the results: `SELECT
  COUNT(*) as '# TABLES',
  CONCAT(ROUND(sum(data_length) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') as DATA,
  CONCAT(ROUND(sum(index_length) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') as INDEXES,
  CONCAT(sum(ROUND(( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2)), 'G') as TOTAL,
  engine as ENGINE
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY engine;`

Comment: Done, thx very much

Comment: you have some InnoDB tables (3GB), but as you said, most of them are in MyISAM format, which doesn't alter much the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with MyISAM is that you cannot create a copy of the database without locking the tables (otherwise the copy may be inconsistent). I would recommend you to research a potential migration to InnoDB.

You will have to execute `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` in order to lock all tables in read only mode, then copy all the `.MYD`, `.MYI` and `.frm` files from the filesystem (basically, your entire `datadir`). Once you copy those files, you will want to get your binary log coordinates so you can setup replication with `SHOW MASTER STATUS`. If you cannot setup replication, you will have to leave the server in  `read_only` mode while you setup the other one. Otherwise, `UNLOCK TABLES;`. In previous versions of MySQL, you had the [`mysqlhotcopy`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) script that automatized some of those tasks for MyISAM.

**EDIT**: As you have some InnoDB tables, you must be sure to copy the whole data directory (including `ib_logfile*` and `ib_data*`ones), and not only single files- otherwise the copy won't succeed.

Setup the new server copying the files to the right place, start the new server, and you can now setup a [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html) between the old server and the new one. Once you double check that the setup is correct and the `key_buffer`/buffer pool is warm, you will put the old server in `read_only` mode and failover your applications to the new one.

The idea is to avoid [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), which is slower for exporting, but above all, for importing, although it is easier to use. That it is what it is internally executed with phpMyAdmin's "export/import database" feature.

I know this is a high level overview, but I recommend you to start reasearching the links I mentioned and about MySQL replication and asking additional specific questions if needed.

Comment: Thanks very much, your help is very much appriciated!
Can you tell me how long did you think will we need, if we say it will work in first try, to lock the tables for this 80GB

Comment: @Kovu Lock granting should take seconds, unless you have long SELECTs running or lots of buffered content. Obviously I recommend you to do all of this on the lowest possible load time (e.g. night). The copy process (while you held the lock) will be as fast as copying 80 GB of files from disk. I recommend you to try the process on a test system first.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have something like log shipping as in SQL Server?
That's what I would use in SQL Server. A matter of a few minutes downtime.